# Labels truncated in condenameone

Tags: codenameone

We have a simple Label - TextField on a login page for username and password. Recently the label text has become truncated on many devices (not all though) we have tried playing about with the number of columns etc in the TextField but nothing has worked.

Has something changed recently as this wasn't an issue before? Is there a way to force the text in the label to display?

Thanks

Comment: We always change things such as paddings, fonts etc. in the default native UI. If you have a screenshot ideally before/after screenshots but even after alone would be OK. The source that produced it might also be useful.